# DataContractSerializer not supporting rectangular Arrays

Tags: c#

I ran into an unexpected problem today, attempting to serialize/deserialize a DataContract containing a bool[,] DataMember. Neither csc nor runtime objected this definition, however the values in the deserialized bool[,] DataMember just weren't correct. After reading [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/96d99982-bace-4c3e-93cb-7c9ca905f317/), my initial reaction was to convert the problematic property into a jagged array. I had to abandon that approach soon however since [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163995.aspx) informs that jagged arrays perform miserably when accessed diagonally or randomly (exactly my use case). So I ended up writing a curated version of the solution proposed in the above msdn thread (convert rectangular to jagged and visa versa upon export/import, see code excerpts below) and that works fine.

```
public object GetDeserializedObject(object obj, Type targetType)
{
    if (obj is GridArrayWrapper)
    {
        bool[,] arr;
        GridArrayWrapper wrapper = (GridArrayWrapper)obj;
        if (wrapper.Array == null) return null;
        int d0 = wrapper.Array.Length;
        if (d0 == 0)
        {
            return new bool[0, 0];
        }
        var d1 = wrapper.Array[0].Length;
        arr = new bool[d0, d1];
        for (int i = 0; i < d0; i++)
        {
            if (wrapper.Array[i].Length != d1) throw new ArgumentException("Not a rectangular array");
            for (var j = 0; j < d1; j++)
            {
                arr[i, j] = wrapper.Array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    return obj;
}

public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
{
    if (obj is bool[,])
    {
        bool[,] arr = (bool[,])obj;
        GridArrayWrapper wrapper = new GridArrayWrapper();
        int d0 = arr.GetLength(0);
        int d1 = arr.GetLength(1);
        wrapper.Array = new bool[d0][];
        for (int i = 0; i < wrapper.Array.Length; i++)
        {
            wrapper.Array[i] = new bool[d1];
            for (int j = 0; j < d1; j++)
            {
                wrapper.Array[i][j] = arr[i, j];
            }
        }
        return wrapper;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

I'm wondering however if there is a more concise solution to this or another approach.

Comment: "that jagged arrays perform miserably" - but does that really matter compared with the I/O, conversion and serialization?

Comment: The persistence format and the runtime format don't have to be the same

Comment: At the core of the application the array in question is accessed millions of times (and it is a phone app where CPUs are not that powerful). Serialization only takes place upon App deactivate or close (infrequent).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing GetDeserializedObject & GetObjectToSerialize, i'd expose a different object for serialization. A single dimensional array would suffice by the way.
I would do this :

```
//No Datamember here
public bool[,] Data;

[DataMember(Name="Data")]
public bool[] XmlData
{
  get {
    bool[] tmp = new bool[Data.GetLength(0) * Data.GetLength(1)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(Data, 0, tmp, 0, tmp.Length * sizeof(bool));
    return tmp;
  }
  set {
    bool[,] tmp = new bool[,];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(value, 0, tmp, 0, value.Length * sizeof(bool));
    this.Data = tmp;  
  }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. instancing a multi-dimensional array must have the size specified. Therefore new bool[,]; is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you need a multidimensional array in the first place?

If you use a single dimension array, you just have to compute the proper index, with a very simple computation:

```
array[x, y]
```

becomes

```
array[(y * width) + x]
```

---

EDIT: as mentionned in comments, you'll then lose some useful bounds checking. If that's an issue, you could re-add them:

```
if (x < 0 || x > width || y < 0 || y > height)
   throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
```

Note: the y cases would be already thrown by the array if the x is valid.

Comment: True, but you lose some elements of bounds checking (for a `3x4` array, you could specify an index of `(6,1)`, and that will still compute a position within the overall array)

Comment: You're right, these checks need to be done by hand. Updating.